# dayname function

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to find the next 6 months dayname from given date in mysql

```
select {fn dayname(date)} 
from time
```

input: 20200531
Output:
monday 2020-06-01
tuesday 2020-06-02
wednesday 2020-06-03
thursday 2020-06-04
friday 2020-06-05
saturday 2020-06-06
sunday 2020-05-31

Comment: Please provide sample results and a tag for the database you are using.

Comment: Hi, please remember we are not sitting beside you and we are not clairvoyant. If you give us an example of the inputs and the desired outputs based on that input then maybe we can help you

Comment: input=20190601 then in output must be like :2019/06/02: sunday 2019/06/03 monday

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DAYNAME(DATE_ADD("2017-06-15", INTERVAL 6 MONTH);
```

This works in MySQL to add 6 months to date and get date name.i hope this is what you wanted.

Comment: thanks ,but i have given a variable a in which we get date ,then from that day we must next date with weekday.

Comment: output :                                                                                                           
monday 2020-06-01
tuesday 2020-06-02
wednesday 2020-06-03
thursday 2020-06-04
friday 2020-06-05
saturday 2020-06-06
sunday 2020-05-31

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT DAYNAME( DATE_ADD( "2019-06-21 09:34:21", INTERVAL 6 MONTH ) )
```

Comment: This is a low-quality answer. Try adding some details. Why do you think this approach is the best?

Comment: in place of date i want to use variable

Comment: You can achieve by using loop on given date. For more [detail](https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?20,407258)